# Does Wii browser support WebSockets?

Tags: tcp, websocket, wii

Does the browser in the Wii support websockets? I know the Wii uses opera, but I just want to make sure since I don't have a way of testing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [Internet Channel on the Wii was based off of Opera 9](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wii/en_na/gi_channels.jsp?menu=internet). Opera did not have any web socket support of any kind until [Opera 11](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2010/12/17/new-html5-features-in-opera-11) and even now is disabled by default.

Comment: Is Flash installed? If so you could fallback to a Flash Socket. See: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js